# Help regarding alpha-beta search

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I am self teaching myself basics of AI, from the internet, I am trying to do pset3 of MIT's 6.034 here at
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/pages/assignments/

the specs of the pset wants to implement a alpha-beta search algorithm with the following signature

```
def alpha_beta_search(board, depth,
                      eval_fn,
                      # NOTE: You should use get_next_moves_fn when generating
                      # next board configurations, and is_terminal_fn when
                      # checking game termination.
                      # The default functions set here will work
                      # for connect_four.
                      get_next_moves_fn,
              is_terminal_fn)
```

the pset has one helper file where you could use the provided code and some tests to debug your implementation. The file together with the test that i am having trouble with is as follows

```
class Node:
    """
    Representation of a generic game tree node.
    Each node holds
    1. a label
    2. a static value (internal nodes
    generally have a None static value)
    3. node type  {MIN, MAX}
    4. list of child nodes.
        """
    def __init__(self, label, value, node_type, children=[]):
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
        self.node_type = node_type
        self.children = children

    def set_children(self, child_nodes):
        """Set the children of this tree node"""
        if not self.children:
            self.children = []
        for child in child_nodes:
            self.children.append(child)

    def get_children(self):
        return self.children

    def __str__(self):
        """Print the value of this node."""
        if self.value is None:
            return self.label
        else:
            return "%s[%s]" %(self.label, self.value)

    def add(self, child):
        """Add children to this node."""
        if not self.children:
            self.children = []      
        self.children.append(child)

    def num_children(self):
        """Find how many children this node has."""
        if self.children:
            return len(self.children)
        else:
            return 0

def tree_as_string(node, depth=0):
    """
    Generates a string representation of the tree
    in a space indented format
    """
    static_value = tree_eval(node)
    # buf = "%s%s:%s\n" %(" "*depth, node.label, static_value)
    buf = f"{' '*depth}{node.label}:{static_value}\n"
    for elt in node.children:
        buf += tree_as_string(elt, depth+1)
    return buf

def make_tree(tup):
    """
    Generates a Node tree from a tuple formatted tree
    """
    return make_tree_helper(tup, "MAX")
    
def make_tree_helper(tup, node_type):
    """Generate a Tree from tuple format"""
    n = Node(tup[0], tup[1], node_type)
    # print(f"tup in make_tree_helper : {tup}")
    children = []
    if len(tup) > 2:
        if node_type == "MAX":
            node_type = "MIN"
        else:
            node_type = "MAX"
        
    for c in range(2,len(tup)):
        # print(f"adding {tup[c]} as child")
        children.append(make_tree_helper(tup[c], node_type))
    n.set_children(children)
    
    return n

def is_at_depth(depth, node):
    """
    is_terminal_fn for fixed depth trees
    True if depth == 0 has been reached.
    """
    return depth <= 0

def is_leaf(depth, node):
    """
    is_terminal_fn for variable-depth trees.
    Check if a node is a leaf node.
    """
    return node.num_children() == 0


def tree_get_next_move(node):
    """
    get_next_move_fn for trees
    Returns the list of next moves for traversing the tree
    """
    return [(n.label, n) for n in node.children]

def tree_eval(node):
    """
    Returns the static value of a node
    """
    # if node.value is not None:
    # if node.node_type == "MIN":
    #     return -node.value
    # elif node.node_type == "MAX":
    #     return node.value
    #     else:
    #         raise Exception("Unrecognized node type: %s" %(node.node_type))
    # else:
    #     return None
    if node.value is not None:
        if node.node_type == "MIN":
            return -node.value
        elif node.node_type == "MAX":
            return node.value
        else:
            # raise Exception("Unrecognized node type: %s" %(node.node_type))
            raise Exception("Unrecognized node type: %s" % (node.node_type,))

    else:
        return None



def TEST_2(expected):
    from lab3 import alpha_beta_search
    tup_tree = ("A", None,
        ("B", None,
         ("C", None,
          ("D", 6),
          ("E", 4)),
         ("F", None,
          ("G", 8),
          ("H", 6))
         ),
        ("I", None,
         ("J", None,
          ("K", 4),
          ("L", 0)),
         ("M", None,
          ("N", 2),
          ("O", 2))
         )
        )
    tree = make_tree(tup_tree)
    print (f"TREE_2:\n{tree_as_string(tree)}")
    v = alpha_beta_search(tree, 10,
              tree_eval,
              tree_get_next_move,
              is_leaf)
    print (f"BEST MOVE: {v}") 
    print (f"EXPECTED: {expected}" )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run basic tests using trees.
    TEST_2("B")
```

The test given here I decided to first solve it on a paper and then implement it in code. My approach on paper is been that I do a depth first search, with alpha equals to -infinity, and beta equals to +ve infinity, and pass alpha and beta from a parent to a child until i reach at a leaf, at the leaf check if value after evaluation is negative, if its negative, I check if its greater than the alpha of that node, if yes i set alpha to that value. And if the value after evaluation is +ve im checking beta of that node if the value is lesser than the current beta, I set beta to that value.
when done with the leaf node, I check if alpha of leaf is greater than the alpha of parent node, if yes, I set alpha of parent to that value, similarliy i check if beta of leaf is less than the beta of parent, if yes i set beta of parent to that value.
Then i recurse and repeat this for every node
Dont know y in the test for the given tree how is the expected value is "B", wherease if i solve it on paper B gets a alpha of -6 and beta = infinity, and node "I" gets alpha of 0 and beta of infinity. So naturally A that is the root would choose I right? Why is it B? What am I doing wrong here?